# Using transaction in cursor with try..catch

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a large stored procedure which utilises a cursor. I want to put each instance of the cursor processing into a transaction, with a try-catch on the one insert, which on failure would terminate that transaction, back any inserts it did and then move to the next cursor instance. However, I am struggling with structuring this.

An example of what it looks like in brief is below. Basically I am trying to structure the try-catch for the patient insert to rollback the transaction and go onto the next cursor value when the patient insert fails.

Thanks

```
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[Import_Archive_Record]
    @PatientNumber varchar(10),
    @PracticeId int
    as
    begin   
          DECLARE csr1 CURSOR for
          select PatientNumber from ArchiveFull.dbo.ArchiveMasters where imported = 0 and PracticeId = 
         @PracticeId and PatientNumber = @PatientNumber
          
          open csr1
          fetch next from csr1 into @PatNo
          while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
          begin 
          
            insert into Member....
    
            select @memberId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
            print 'new member ' + cast(@memberId as varchar(10))
    
            --insert patient
           BEGIN TRY
            select @initials = PatientInitials ,@surname = PatientSurname ,@name = PatientFirstname, 
            @DateOfBirth = DOBStr,@PatientCentury = DOBCen 
              from ArchiveFull.dbo.ArchiveMasters
            where ArchiveFull.dbo.ArchiveMasters.PatientNumber = @PatNo
               and imported = 0
               and PracticeId = @PracticeId
    
            set @patientID = null
            select @patientID =  id from Patient
                where Initials = @initials
                and Surname = @surname
                and Name = @name
                and MemberId = @memberId
            
            print 'patientid ' + cast(@patientID as varchar(10))
    
            set @DOB = dbo.getVisitdate(@PatientCentury,@DateOfBirth)
            
            if @patientID is null
            begin
                insert into Patient(Name, Surname,Initials,MemberId,PostalSuburb,PostalCity,PostalCode,PostBox,Gender, DateofBirth,IDNumber,DependentCode,RelationToMember,AlternativesRelation,EMailAddress,CellPhone,Title)
                select  PatientFirstname,PatientSurname, coalesce(PatientInitials,'.'),@memberId,PatientAddress1, PatientAddress2, PatientAddress3,PatientAddress4,Gender,@DOB,PatientIDNumber,1,1,0,PatientEmail, CellNumber,PatientTitle
                  from ArchiveFull.dbo.ArchiveMasters
                 where PatientNumber = @PatNo
                    and imported = 0
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

END CATCH
                select @patientID =  SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    
                print 'new patientid ' + cast(@patientID as varchar(10))
            end
            
    
            set @BranchId = (select top 1 id from Branch where practiceid = @practiceId and ModalityRooms like concat('%', @BranchCode,'%'))
            
            set @visitId = null
            select @visitId = id from Visit
            where BookingNumber = @PatNo
            and BranchId = @BranchId
            
            if @visitId is null
            begin
                    declare @visitDate datetime
                    declare @century int
                    declare @date int
                    declare @DoctorCode nvarchar (max)
                    declare @DoctorSurname nvarchar (max)
                    declare @wca bit
            
                    select @century = Century, @date = ExamDateStr, @DoctorCode = RefDocCode, @DoctorSurname = RefDoc, @wca=WCA 
                      from ArchiveFull.dbo.ArchiveMasters
                     where ArchiveFull.dbo.ArchiveMasters.PatientNumber = @PatNo
                        and imported = 0
                        and PracticeId = @PracticeId
                    update testlist
                      set century = @century, examdate = @date
                    where patno = @PatNo
    
                    set @visitDate = isnull(dbo.getVisitdate(@century,@date),'19000101')
    
                    set @DoctorId = null
                    set @DoctorId = dbo.getDoctorIdRadmin(@DoctorCode,@practiceId)
    
                    
                    insert into Visit(Date,EndMonth, EndYear,NewBorn,HospitalClaim,WCA,WorkersComp,RAF,RoadAccidentFund,Examined,Booking,BookingNumber,PatientId,Notes,PreAuthorise,PreAuthNumber,BranchId,DoctorId, Receipted, ArchiveId)
                    select @visitDate, MONTH(@visitDate), YEAR(@visitdate) ,0,0,0,'',0,'',1,1,@PatNo,@patientID,'',0,AUTHNO,@BranchId,@DoctorId, 0, @archiveid
                      from ArchiveFull.dbo.ArchiveMasters
                     where ArchiveFull.dbo.ArchiveMasters.PatientNumber = @PatNo
                        and imported = 0
                        and PracticeId = @PracticeId

  fetch next from csr1 into @PatNo
  end
  close csr1
  deallocate csr1
```

Comment: Why use a `CURSOR` in a first place here?

Comment: This is just a partial snapshot of the stored procedure. It has about a dozen more inserts. It reads from a bulk import table, then inserts into the live database, importing multiple lines per imported patno, each one on the same visitno. So the cursor divides the processing up so each visit gets processed individually.

Comment: Why? SQL is a set based language, why not process the data in sets?

Comment: Also, you say you couldn't get it to work, but I can't see any transactions declared in your attempt. Please do show us the attempt you have which includes your attempt to get the transaction working.

Comment: The problem here is that we are dealing with two import tables. The main one with the patno is 6 million rows, the detail one over 50 million rows. Each one in the main table can have from 0 to x detail rows. (the biggest seems to be over 300 rows on the detail). Teh cursor means that the import of the main visit come sin, and then its detail rows are inserted into multiple tables linking back to the visit. Since processing is required between insert, this is far easier in a cursor import than a pure set based transaction since the visit details are not known prior to processing.

Comment: And yes, you don't see the transaction in my code above since I am struggling to structure it and get it to work, That is what I am asking here: how do I structure this so the transaction will work with rollback based on the try-catch.

Comment: What does it mean "The import of the main visit comes in"?

Comment: The documentation comes with plenty of examples. Have you had a look at them? For example [Example C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-using-trycatch-with-xact_state)?

Comment: @SteveC It is a transactional system for radiologists. So when a patient visits the radiologist (a visit), multiple things can happen, multiple forms of medical procedures, multiple medical materials used etc. So each line on the main table brings in the patient details and sets up the visit. After that the detail table brings in the information to populateprocedures, materials etc

Comment: @Larnu I've looked at the examples- what I am struggling with is the placement of the catch(with rollback transaction) and commit transaction to the fetch next. There are a couple of hundred lines between the patient insert where I have the try and fetch next... so my issue is how do I place the catch to allow the rollback and then move to the next cursor vs where to place the commit transaction when successful to move to the next cursor

Comment: All of those cursors could be removed.  300 rows is the maximum rows/insert of transaction?

Comment: ah, it could be involved tho.  Are you just looking for a try/catch with throw example so you can extend it yourself?

Comment: @SteveC The maximum roset is undefined, it could be any number, that is just the current data. As for the try-catch, the problem is that sometimes patient data comes in incomplete and is missing data for "not null" fields. Often data that we cannot just guess at or leave undefined so it has to be thrown back so the correct data can be obtained and entered. The final version will include error logging and recording so a reportcan be drawn to show which were not imported and why so the data can be fixed and imported.

Comment: @SteveCThe other issue is that each detail lie does not go to the same table but needs to be processed to determine its type, then matched and stored. Thus import things like types of procedures, amount of rads used etc may be on online where as the other will contain a medicine and dosage information,,, getting that wrong could be catastrophic

Comment: I'm not sure I'm knowing enough to propose an answer.

Comment: Try starting with a _minimal_ example and sorting it out on your own. (Just one input and one output table, a few rows of data, a simple "error" to catch. If it works then build on it until it fails or you're done.) If you can't get it to work then post the complete example with DDL, sample data, SP, expected results and explain what isn't cooperating. A [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) example makes it easier for us to help you.